# Heading and Normal styled text on same line in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, newlines

Is it possible to add Heading 1 and Normal styled text on the same line in MS Word (apart from using tables)?

http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=9944#2

> 1. Type the "Heading 1" text on one line, and press Enter.
> 2. Type the "Normal" text on the next line.
> 3. Click on the ¶ button (on the Standard toolbar at the top of your
>    screen) to show non-printing characters.
> 4. Select the ¶ mark at the end of the heading 1 line, and click on
>    Format | Font | check the "Hidden" box.
> 5. Click on the ¶ button again to hide non-printing characters.

That method doesn't work for me:
[image]

Comment: A style is just a collection of formatting.   Format your line as needed. Otherwise Tables is the only other method.

Comment: It is working normally on my side. See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQBig.png). What happens if you press the delete button (just after heading 1).

Comment: Recommend you add your version of word to the question as it works for me!

Comment: John, a style is a collection of formatting but it is also a container, in Word. The Style Separator allows you to use that container in other places in the document. Direct Formatting does not. http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Style_Separator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What you want is what is called a Style Separator.

[image: screenshot]Here is my writing in my page on styles about [the Style Separator](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/styles.htm#Style_Separator). The keyboard shortcut for this in the Windows version is `Ctrl+Alt+Enter`.

The hidden paragraph mark is a workaround.

Once you have one, you can copy and paste if you want. Here is a [temporary link to a template](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1jssv6kjvsv79w/Style%20Separator%20Sample%202022-04-04.dotx?dl=0) with two of them you could use if you cannot produce your own.